# Как разместить 3 кнопку в самом низу LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

Как разместить 3 кнопку в самом низу LinearLayout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@color/Dark"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Часть 1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="30sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Поместите перед нижней кнопкой вот это:

```
<Space android:weight="1" android:width="match_parent" android:height="0dp"/>
```

Благодаря весу, оно займёт все незанятое место в контейнере. Правда, при этом, всё остальное сдвитентся вверх. Чтобы этого избежать можно, например, такой же элемент расположить в самом начале контейнера.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/Dark"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Часть 1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]